# Google Cloud MySQL Truncating Timestamps from CSV Import

Tags: mysql, csv, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

From a CSV that looks like:

```
2018-01-18 13:23:48.878,KERRIE PAUSSA,CLOCK IN LUNCH
2018-01-18 16:57:46.466,ANDREW PEDERSON,CLOCK OUT PM
2018-01-18 17:29:57.731,AARON RICHARDS,CLOCK OUT PM
2018-01-18 17:30:11.903,DANIEL PURBRICK,CLOCK OUT PM
```

Google Cloud SQL is rendering:

```
Timestamp           | Name       | Punch_Type       | id   |
+---------------------+------------+------------------+------+
| 2018-01-18 06:59:15 | FRED MOORE | CLOCK IN AM      | 3427 |
| 2018-01-18 12:00:43 | FRED MOORE | CLOCK OUT LUNCH  | 3433 |
| 2018-01-18 12:32:03 | FRED MOORE | CLOCK IN LUNCH   | 3437 |
    | 3484 | 17:38:28 | FRED MOORE | CLOCK OUT PM
     | 3490 |06:59:18 | FRED MOORE | CLOCK IN AM
 | 3498 |-22 12:23:04 | FRED MOORE | CLOCK OUT LUNCH
  | 3504 |22 12:54:40 | FRED MOORE | CLOCK IN LUNCH
+---------------------+------------+------------------+------+
```

However, when only the Timestamp column is selected, the data appear normal:

```
+---------------------+
| Timestamp           |
+---------------------+
| 2018-01-18 06:59:15 |
| 2018-01-18 12:00:43 |
| 2018-01-18 12:32:03 |
| 2018-01-18 17:38:28 |
| 2018-01-22 06:59:18 |
| 2018-01-22 12:23:04 |
| 2018-01-22 12:54:40 |
+---------------------+
```

This is the only query that returns normal values for `Timestamp`, though, and the data aren't displaying properly in the application view either. I'm flummoxed - is this something I've done wrong, or something wonky with Cloud SQL?!

Comment: Have you looked at your `Punch_Type` data to see if there are any embedded linefeeds? That's what it looks like, based on the output table. I don't think it's an issue with your date fields (looks like the `id`, normally the last column, gets shown over top of the date, which is why I'm guessing there is a newline character in there)

Comment: @DavidMakogon They do specify 1 row per line, comma separated: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/, and other files formatted the same way have come out fine = /

Comment: I wasn't arguing about format. I was simply pointing out that, the way it's printing out, it just has the look of an embedded linefeed (character 10, `\n`). Have you tried viewing just the `Punch_Type` and `id` fields together?

Comment: All fields have /n characters, though it's only a problem in this one case.  Punch_Type does overrun id - will try to strip out the /n characters and see if that does the trick.

Comment: Problem seems to be with some trailing white space in Punch_Type:
`+-----------------+
| Punch_Type      |
+-----------------+
 |CLOCK IN LUNCH
+-----------------+`

However, using the TRIM function doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was a carriage return /r character at the end of each line.  Very annoying!  TRIM worked great:

```
update Daily_clock_totals SET Punch_Type = TRIM(TRAILING '\r' FROM Punch_Type);
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSV file data has wrong format.

> The format of CSV files that Cloud SQL accepts is equivalent to using the MySQL statements "LOAD DATA INFILE ... CHARACTER SET 'utf8' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\"'.

Comment: Why would other files identically formatted work just fine, though?

Comment: They might have different data in other columns.

Comment:  Still not getting it. Can you be more specific?